# Unable to get Codeigniter ODBC to work with select

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord, odbc

I have been struggling trying to find out what I'm doing wrong for a couple days now.  I have a an ODBC connection setup up a a secondary database where I am strictly selecting data from.

So I know the connection is working and there is something I am doing wrong in the active record.  Here is me function

```
public function get_pm_counts($date, $date_equal='<=') {    
    //connect to the history server
    $this->histdb = $this->load->database('locator', true);

    $query = "SELECT query_name, pmcount, entry_date, company_code, orig_system FROM (pmcounts) WHERE plant_code = '2970' AND entry_date = '01/07/2014' AND pmcount > 0";
    $result = odbc_exec($this->histdb->conn_id, $query);
    echo '<pre>';
    while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($result))
    {
        print_r($row);         
        echo '<br>';
    }
    echo '</pre>';

    //run the query                             
    $this->histdb
        ->select('query_name, pmcount, entry_date, company_code, orig_system')   
        ->where('plant_code', '2970')
        ->where('entry_date '.$date_equal, $date)
        ->where('pmcount >', 0); 
    $query = $this->histdb->get('pmcounts');
    print_r($this->histdb->last_query());
    return $query;  
}
```

Obviously the first part of the function I am jsut running the query outside of active record and then I try the exact same query with active record.  When I print the first query, outside active record, I return the results I expect.  But running the active record query I get the following when I print $query:

```
CI_DB_odbc_result Object
(
[conn_id] => Resource id #8
[result_id] => Resource id #10
[result_array] => Array
    (
    )

[result_object] => Array
    (
    )

[custom_result_object] => Array
    (
    )

[current_row] => 0
[num_rows] => 0
[row_data] => 
)
```

------ EDIT------

When I print the $this->histdb object I get the following:

```
CI_DB_odbc_driver Object
(
[dbdriver] => odbc
[_escape_char] => 
[_like_escape_str] =>  {escape '%s'} 
[_like_escape_chr] => !
[_count_string] => SELECT COUNT(*) AS 
[_random_keyword] =>  RND(1389212207)
[ar_select] => Array
    (
    )

[ar_distinct] => 
[ar_from] => Array
    (
    )

[ar_join] => Array
    (
    )

[ar_where] => Array
    (
    )

[ar_like] => Array
    (
    )

[ar_groupby] => Array
    (
    )

[ar_having] => Array
    (
    )

[ar_keys] => Array
    (
    )

[ar_limit] => 
[ar_offset] => 
[ar_order] => 
[ar_orderby] => Array
    (
    )

[ar_set] => Array
    (
    )

[ar_wherein] => Array
    (
    )

[ar_aliased_tables] => Array
    (
    )

[ar_store_array] => Array
    (
    )

[ar_caching] => 
[ar_cache_exists] => Array
    (
    )

[ar_cache_select] => Array
    (
    )

[ar_cache_from] => Array
    (
    )

[ar_cache_join] => Array
    (
    )

[ar_cache_where] => Array
    (
    )

[ar_cache_like] => Array
    (
    )

[ar_cache_groupby] => Array
    (
    )

[ar_cache_having] => Array
    (
    )

[ar_cache_orderby] => Array
    (
    )

[ar_cache_set] => Array
    (
    )

[ar_no_escape] => Array
    (
    )

[ar_cache_no_escape] => Array
    (
    )

[username] => hist****
[password] => *********
[hostname] => WMSlocator
[database] => locator
[dbprefix] => 
[char_set] => utf8
[dbcollat] => utf8_general_ci
[autoinit] => 1
[swap_pre] => 
[port] => 
[pconnect] => 
[conn_id] => Resource id #10
[result_id] => Resource id #11
[db_debug] => 1
[benchmark] => 0.1088068485
[query_count] => 1
[bind_marker] => ?
[save_queries] => 1
[queries] => Array
    (
        [0] => SELECT query_name, pmcount, entry_date, company_code, orig_system
FROM (pmcounts)
WHERE plant_code =  '2970'
AND entry_date =  '01/07/2014'
AND pmcount > 0
    )

[query_times] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0.1088068485
    )

[data_cache] => Array
    (
    )

[trans_enabled] => 1
[trans_strict] => 1
[_trans_depth] => 0
[_trans_status] => 1
[cache_on] => 
[cachedir] => 
[cache_autodel] => 
[CACHE] => 
[_protect_identifiers] => 1
[_reserved_identifiers] => Array
    (
        [0] => *
    )

[stmt_id] => 
[curs_id] => 
[limit_used] => 
[stricton] => 
)
```

I see the query time as 0.1 seconds so does that mean the query ran?  Having I real hard time figuring this out and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong with active record.  I am fairly new to codeigniter.

Thanks Nick

Answer (score 0):

try to echo  $query->result(); and use:

```
return $query->result();
```

Comment: you've probably got a problem with the date you are using in the line:  ->where('entry_date '.$date_equal, $date).  I'd suggest starting there and trying to fix that line.  Also, check the last query against your other query

Comment: That's not it either.  I printed the $this->histdb->last_query() and copied to the first query string.  So they are the exact same.  But I just trying hard coding a date and got the same results as before.  Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: its not the same because your first query says "entry_date = '01/07/2014'" but your second query is coded (via your get_pm_counts function) to say "entry_date <= '01/07/2014'

Comment: It is the same. '<=' is the default.  Right above return $query is the print last query function which I did first and then copied that string and pasted it in as the string for the first query that I run directly through the ODBC functions.  This way I knew I was running the same query.  So I know it is not the query.